# How do I achieve this layout without using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I want a basic full width layout with a 250px sidebar on the right. Here's roughly what I want:

```
<-------Content-------><--250px sidebar-->
<---------------100% width--------------->
```

Is this possible without Javascript or tables?

Comment: What versions of IE you need to support?

Comment: IE7 or higher, though I can include IE-specific code if I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course:

see http://jsfiddle.net/whTwg/4/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <div id="main">Main</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
}
#main-wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
}
#sidebar-wrapper{
    float:right;
    width:250px;
    max-width:50%;/* You should set a max-width */
}
/*Here you can add borders, paddings and margins */
#main{
    background:#aaf;
    border:10px solid blue;
}
#sidebar{
    background:#faa;
    border:10px solid red;
}
```

Note: instead of `#wrapper{overflow:hidden}` (or something different than visible), you could add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after `main-wrapper`.

**Edit**:

You are right, I forgot to add `#main-wrapper{overflow:hidden;}`. I have fixed the link and the code.

Comment: But if I do this, it's clear that some content will be covered by the sidebar: http://jsfiddle.net/whTwg/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="float: left">
  ..... content ......
<div>
<div style="float: right; width: 250px;">
 ..... sidebar .....
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
... other content
```

This is the CSS for the class="clear":

```
div.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

You can set the first div width when you see how much space you have.

Is this helpful?